# Me da fallo cuando si esta definido

Tags: java, java-8, diccionarios, stream, java-stream

Estoy estudiando para un examen y normalmente me sale todo pero en este caso no lo consigo resolver, voy a poner primero el enunciado del problema, luego lo que he escrito yo y por ultimo digo que ocurre:

> agrupaSumaSuperficiePorTipoAcceso: Dado un parámetro `umbralPuntuacion`
> de tipo Double, devuelve un `Map` que a cada valor de `tipoAcceso` le hace
> corresponder la suma de los valores de superficie de los museos con
> dicho valor de `tipoAcceso`, de entre los que cumplen que su propiedad
> puntuacion es menor o igual que el parámetro `umbralPuntuacion`.

```
public Map<TipoAcceso, Integer> agrupaSumaSuperficiePorTipoAcceso(Double umbralPuntuacion) {
        
return
  museos.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        Museo::getTipoAcceso,
        museos.stream().filter(
            p -> p.puntuacion <=umbralPuntuacion).
        mapToInt(
            Museo::getSuperficie).
        sum()));
```

Primero decir que me faltaria comprobar en el diccionario que la clave(`Museo::getTipoAcceso`) es igual a `p.tipoAcceso` pero no se como se hace.

Como no sabia hacer esa parte decidi completar el resto del ejercicio pero resulta que me da este error

`The type Museo does not define getTipoAcceso(T) that is applicable here` en `Museo::getTipoAcceso`. Lo cual me parece raro porque si esta definido y aparte en otra funcion utilice tambien `Museo::` y me daba correcto. Espero que me ayuden y si necesitan mas información, díganlo.

Comment: en realidad va todo seguido pero a la hora de escribirlo pulse enter para poder verlo todo en la pantalla, pero lo voy a editar para no confundir a la gente

Comment: El segundo argumento del método es un *stream* que acaba devolviendo un número, pero no hay ninguna sobrecarga de *groupingBy* que acepte un número como segundo parámetro. El filtro debería ir antes de hacer la recolección de los datos.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo escribo el filter antes del diccionario pero no entiendo que groupingBy no acepte un numero, entonces ¿como hago un diccionario <TipoAcceso, Integer>? ¿Y como escribo en el codigo que el tipoAcceso de la clave debe ser el mismo que el de la lista que se recorre para el valor del diccionario? Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, el filtro no es parte del collection, si tienes que filtrar elementos se hace antes del terminal:

```
museos.stream().
   filter(museo -> museo.puntuacion <= limite).
```

Para combinar valores más allá de una sistema transformación directa usas un *Collector*. Así que haces el groupingBy, y si miras la documentación del API (que para eso está) le pasas no el número sino una instancia de *Collector* que se encargará de calcular el valor asociado

```
museos.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
         Museo::getTipoAcceso,
         new MiCollector()));
```

por suerte, en *java.util.Streams.Collectors* ya hay definidos un montón de los collectors que puedan ser más interesantes, incluyendo *summingInt/Long/etc.*

```
museos.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
         Museo::getTipoAcceso,
         Collectors.summingFloat(Museo::getSuperficie)));
```